# Decision Tree Accuracy: How to calculate leaf node accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, cart, accuracy

Given: A tree where each node is an SVM classifier

Question: How do you calculate a child node's accuracy?

I am able to get the accuracy of each classifier in the tree. I guessed that this is called the conditional accuracy. Thus, the cumulative accuracy would be the previous parent node accuracy multiplied together with the current node?